# Exporting and importing Kickoff Application Launcher's menu?

Tags: kubuntu, kickoff

Is there any way to export and import Kickoff Application Launcher's menu? I use Kubuntu 14.10 Plasma 4.

Comment: The KDE Menu Editor Handbook has a section: 'Transfer application launcher settings'

Comment: @user26687 Feel free to add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [KDE Menu Editor Handbook](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kde-workspace/kmenuedit/kmenuedit.pdf) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170729154909/https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kde-workspace/kmenuedit/kmenuedit.pdf)) has a section: 'Transfer application launcher settings':

> There is no way to transfer menu settings using the GUI, you have to do that manually and copy
>   the following files to the target user:
>
> KMenuEdit stores the menu hierarchy in `menus/applications-kmenuedit.menu` in the folder `$(qtpaths --paths GenericConfigLocation)` and desktop-directories in the folder `$(qtpaths --paths GenericDataLocation)` contains desktop files for submenus you created. In `applications/` in the folder `$(qtpaths --paths GenericDataLocation)` you find the desktop files for the
>   custom items you created.
>   The shortcuts for each application are stored in `kglobalshortcutsrc` in the folder `$(qtpaths --paths GenericConfigLocation)`, but export/import does not work because the UUIDs of the
>   shortcuts do not match up between systems, even though the `.desktop` files are the same. You
>   have to assign all shortcuts manually again.